# Unable to overwrite a Dart/Flutter value - setting today's date correctly on pressing button

Tags: flutter, date, dart, variables

apologies for a simple question but I just started my Dart/Flutter hobby and ran into the following issue: I wanted a simple App that has a defined end date ("dt1") and caluclates the days left based on today's date. I got it to work hardcoding the start date ("dt2) but when I wanted to add a button that gets today's date to overwrite the pre-set start date ("dt2"), it just doesnt acknowledge it - instead it sticks with the dt2 date that I've set earlier.

How do I modify my code so that dt2 gets overwriten by the pressing the button and replaced the value in dt2 with today's date?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2022-06-01");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2022-01-01");
Duration diff = dt1.difference(dt2);

return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Time left at work"),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 131, 48, 75),
    ),
    body: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            DateTime dt2 = DateTime.now();
            Duration diff = dt1.difference(dt2);
            print(dt2);
          },
          child: const Text(
            "Refresh current date",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 10.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Days left: " + diff.inDays.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 40.0,
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Any data which comprises state should be stored as properties on your `State` class. When you update those properties, you also need to do so within a `setState(() {})` callback. Here's a quick introduction to StatefulWidget: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro#changing-widgets-in-response-to-input. The whole User Interface series is worth reading - it'll help a lot with getting Flutter's fundamentals down

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change the value of a variable, you must use `setState`.

Because, you want to change the value at runtime and update UI.

```
setState(() {
    var_you_want_change = new_value_of_the_var;
  });
```

Try this in the `onPressed`:

```
    onPressed: () {
  dt2 = DateTime.now();
  diff = dt1.difference(dt2);
  print(dt2);
  setState(() {
      diff = dt1.difference(dt2);
  });
},
```

Comment: Thanks, Jordan.

I've included the onPressed statement but it still does not update the dt2 value; I feel like it shouldn't be that hard but even after reading the manual/documentation I struggle...

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** this code from your `build` and `onPressed` functions

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2022-06-01");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2022-01-01");
Duration diff = dt1.difference(dt2);
```

Declare `dt1` and `dt2` as your `_HomeState`  fields

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2022-06-01");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2022-01-01");
```

Declare getter named `diff` in your `_HomeState`

```
 class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2022-06-01");
    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2022-01-01");
   
    Duration get diff => dt1.difference(dt2);
```

And finally in `onPressed` (IMPORTANT TO WRAP WITH `setState` in order to update UI ):

```
 onPressed: () {
        setState((){
           dt2 = DateTime.now()
        });
      },
```

Comment: Thanks Kerim, 

Though I can understand the changes, they don't work; the app shows the correct pre-set difference (151 days), and the print command shows the correct today's date, the dt2 still won't be set to the new date when pressing the button.. I'll copy paste the entire code below to be sure I didn't miss anything.

I am very thankful for your support and help!

Comment: You missed the important thing in the answer you posted. You missed to wrap ` dt2 = DateTime.now();` with `setState`. So it will be `setState((){  dt2 = DateTime.now(); })`

Answer (score 0):

This is the current revised code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(const MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse("2022-06-01");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.parse("2022-01-01");

Duration get diff => dt1.difference(dt2);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Work Terminator"),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
    ),
    body: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(children: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(dt2);
            dt2 = DateTime.now();
          },
          child: const Text(
            "Refresh current date",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 10.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Days left: " + diff.inDays.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 40.0,
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    ));
 }
}
```